# I can't figure out why my vector cannot push back

Tags: c++, visual-c++, vector, inventory

I want to make a shop and an inventory in my game but my code keeps crashing. My program crash at addToInventory->addInventoryItems(name); and I am not sure why.

```
// inventory.h
struct InventoryItems
{
    string type;
};
vector<InventoryItems*> inventoryItems;

// inventory.cpp
void Inventory::addInventoryItems(string itemName)
{
    addItem->type = itemName;
    inventoryItems.push_back(addItem);
}


// shop.h
Inventory* addToInventory;

// shop.cpp
void Shop::purchase()
{
    string name = touchableSprites[i]->getSprite()->getName(); 
    addToInventory->addInventoryItems(name);  //crashes here
}
```

Thanks alot!

Comment: Where do you allocate `addToInventory`?

Comment: Where is `addToInventory` allocated? All I see is a pointer declared, where is it allocated as in `new`ed? As it stands you have an unitialised pointer and accessing this results in undefined behaviour or access violation

Comment: please provide a [mcve] there are just to many unknowns in your code, most prominently `addItem`

Answer (score -1):

I guess problem in addItem, because you didn't set type

```
void Inventory::addInventoryItems(string itemName)
{
    InventoryItems addItem;
    addItem->type = itemName;
    inventoryItems.push_back(addItem);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Such errors usually occur when the execution of the function is performed at the same time.

For example : )

```
#define SET_DEFAULT_DELAY {Sleep(100)}

InventoryItems* addToInventory;
TCHAR g_tszParam[MAX_PATH];

DWORD WINAPI _VECTOR_OPERATION_01(LPVOID lParam)
{
    while(TRUE)
    {
        if(0 == _tcsicmp(g_tszParam, _T("Default_Value"))
        {
            addToInventory->addInventoryItems(g_tszparam);
        }
        SET_DEFAULT_DELAY;

    }
}

DWORD WINAPI _VECTOR_OPERATION_02(LPVOID lParam)
{
    while(TRUE)
    {
        if(0 == _tcsicmp(g_tszParam, _T("Special_Value"))
        {
            addToInventory->addInventoryItems(g_tszparam);
        }
        SET_DEFAULT_DELAY;
    }
}

int _tmain()
{
    ...
    HANDLE hThread[2];
    hThread[0] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, _VECTOR_OPERATION_01, NULL, 0, 0);
    if(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != hThread[0])
    {
        CloseHandle(hThread[0]);
    }
    hThread[1] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, _VECTOR_OPERATION_02, NULL, 0, 0);
    if(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != hThread[1])
    {
        CloseHandle(hThread[1]);
    }
    ...
    return 1;
}
```

In this case, the result of thread execution depends on `g_tszParam` values. However, if one thread executes a Vector-related function while another executes a Vector-related function in another thread, a conflict occurs.

I don't know what the speculator is because I don't have your source code.
But it seems to me this is the case why that error occured.